# ATmega328P, simple counter interrupt example not working - frustrated

Tags: avr, atmega

I honestly cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have a LED and an oscilloscope probe attached to the LED at port B3, but the output is flat 2V for some reason.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define LED 3

void tog(void)
{
    PORTB ^= (1 << LED);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    DDRB |= (1 << LED);

    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);

    OCR0A = 0xF9;

    TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);

    TCNT0 = 0;
    sei();

    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS02);


    while (1)
    {
        i++;
    }
}

ISR (TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
    tog();
}
```

Comment: "the output is flat 2V" - Whats your supply voltage?

Comment: Is the LED working if you remove your timer code and just leave the line where you set the LED on?

Comment: I just tried your program as is. My scope shows a nice square wave on PB3.